# How to condition Capistrano deployment on a confirmed server IP

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

We have different servers environments such as `staging` and `production`. I want Capistrano to check whether or not I'm pushing to the correct server so that we don't accidentally push it to the wrong server.

Basically, if I want to push to production, for example, it would first confirm that it's the right IP address for the type `cap production deploy` or else the process would stop and return an error message.

Is this possible? How best to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have your branches set up so that accidentally typing `cap production deploy` will not hurt

But to be extra cautious you can add a task that gets `hostnane` or `ifconfig` output, runs `before 'deploy:started'` and fails/throws an error if current stage is not what it should be

Comment: Do you have any sample code? Specifically, how would you get hostname or IP returned?

Comment: Use capistrano's `capture` method, it runs command on remote and returns output

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something simpler and not as elaborate which I think accomplishes the same thing. I just made sure to use the actual IP address of the servers in my deployment code rather than use the the url.

So, instead of this:

`server 'demo.example.com', :web, :app, :worker, :db, :cache, primary: true`

Use this:

`server '100.100.100.100', :web, :app, :worker, :db, :cache, primary: true`

This makes it impossible to deploy to the wrong server as the your DNS won't be interpreting the route.